# how replace input with textarea fields

Tags: html

I am currently working on an html5 project in which there is a lot of `input` fields that I want to replace by `textarea`.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="Questions" name="texte1"/>
<input type="text" id="Questions" name="texte2"/>
<input type="text" id="Questions" name="texte3"/>
```

There is 200 inputs that I want to change by:

```
<textarea id="Questions" name="texte1"></textarea> 
<textarea id="Questions" name="texte2"></textarea> 
<textarea id="Questions" name="texte3"></textarea>
```

but I can't really use the *search and replace tool* because the name is different for every input So I was wondering if anyone of you knows a quick way to replace all my inputs by text area without changing the names 1 by 1 on my code.

Comment: You need a criterion that tells you which inputs need to be replaced. What do they all have in common? Also note that you cannot have more than one element per page with the same value for `id`, so the HTML you show is invalid.

Comment: Okay thank you so should i use class instead of id ?
And they all have everything in common excepted the name that is different.

Comment: Did you try using `pug`?

Comment: I didn't, i will inform me about this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a criterion that tells you which inputs need to be replaced. What do they all have in common? Also note that you cannot have more than one element per page with the same value for `id`, so the HTML you show is invalid.

So for the example code I'm assuming that all inputs that need to be replaced have a CSS class `replace-me`:

```js
document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const toReplace = [...document.querySelectorAll('.replace-me')]
  for (const input of toReplace) {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
    const parent = input.parentNode
    textarea.id = input.id
    textarea.name = input.name
    textarea.value = input.value
    parent.removeChild(input)
    parent.appendChild(textarea)
  }  
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="replace-me" type="text" value="1" id="i1" name="foo1" />
  <input class="replace-me" type="text" value="2" id="i2" name="foo2" />
  <input class="replace-me" type="text" value="3" id="i3" name="foo3" />
  <input class="replace-me" type="text" value="4" id="i4" name="foo4" />
  <input class="replace-me" type="text" value="5" id="i5" name="foo5" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="replace">Click to replace</button>
```